# Can I take a vm instance and move it to a bootable disk?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

The performance of my suse install under Virtual Box is starting to affect my work, and I really need access to my real multi core CPUs - can I take my vm and stick it on a bootable SD or external HD?

I've read the [How to move existing Linux installation to USB flash drive and make it bootable?](https://superuser.com/questions/133279/howto-move-existing-linux-installation-to-usb-flash-and-make-it-bootable) but it didn't work for me (I'm not convinced I copied correctly).

Any idea as to foolproof way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

All I can suggest is to convert the virtual image into a physical one which you write to the USB disk.

VirtualBox's `VBoxManage` can do this for you...

```
$ VBoxManage clonehd /path/to/suse/disk.vdi /dev/my/usb/disk --format RAW
```

Then try booting of that USB disk and see what happens.